# How to set Spring Boot maven plugin pom proxy values on command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, proxy

I'm trying to use `spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:build-image` to build an application image. I have a profile in my `pom.xml` for build-image,

```
<profile>
    <id>build-image</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <docker>
                        <publishRegistry>
                            <username>${docker.publish.username}</username>
                            <password>${docker.publish.password}</password>
                            <url>https://registry.example.com</url>
                        </publishRegistry>
                    </docker>
                    <publish>true</publish>
                    <image>
                        <env>
                            <HTTP_PROXY>https://proxy.example.com:8080</HTTP_PROXY>
                            <HTTPS_PROXY>https://proxy.example.com:8443</HTTPS_PROXY>
                            <NO_PROXY>localhost,127.0.0.1,example.com</NO_PROXY>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

I'm using a command like this that builds the image,

```
mvn clean deploy \
  -P build-image \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=example/image:latest
```

The question I have is how do I pass other `spring-boot.build-image` properties on the command line? I can set the image name, but can't figure out the other properties. Specifically the proxy configuration. I've tried variations like,

```
mvn clean deploy \
  -P build-image \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=example/image:latest \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.image.env.HTTP_PROXY="https://proxy.example.com:8080" \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.image.env.HTTPS_PROXY="https://proxy.example.com:8443" \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.image.env.NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,example.com"
```

I can't seem to figure out how to set those proxy variables via `-D`. Does anyone know the property to set on the command line?

I've tracked down the [class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/dc5acb00191c2eac09907c39e4d890343bf9848d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildImageMojo.java#L106) where these properties are defined and it lists `env` in the javadoc but I don't see an actual method for setting `env` properties. Here's a snippet of that class,

```
/**
 * Image configuration, with {@code builder}, {@code runImage}, {@code name},
 * {@code env}, {@code cleanCache}, {@code verboseLogging}, {@code pullPolicy}, and
 * {@code publish} options.
 * @since 2.3.0
 */
@Parameter
private Image image;

/**
 * Alias for {@link Image#name} to support configuration via command-line property.
 * @since 2.3.0
 */
@Parameter(property = "spring-boot.build-image.imageName", readonly = true)
String imageName;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using properties inside your configuration:

```
<image>
  <env>
    <HTTP_PROXY>${image.http_proxy}</HTTP_PROXY>
    <HTTPS_PROXY>${image.https_proxy}</HTTPS_PROXY>
    <NO_PROXY>${image.no_proxy}</NO_PROXY>
  </env>
</image>
```

and then pass them using `-DpropertyName`, e.g.

```
mvn clean deploy \
  -P build-image \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=example/image:latest
  -Dimage.http_proxy=...
```

Defaut values can be defined within pom.xml's `properties` element

```
<properties>
  <image.http_proxy>http://some-proxy</image.http_proxy>
</properties>
```